# Rewriting a complex differential form in real coordinates

Tags: differential-geometry, differential-topology, differential-forms

Considering the one-form $$\alpha=\bar{z}_1dz_1+\bar{z}_2dz_2$$ appeared in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3493438/why-is-the-curvature-of-the-connection-barz-1dz-1-barz-2dz-2-on-the-ho), I was trying to rewrite this in real coordinates by taking $z_1=x+yi$ and $z_2=z+wi$. So, we have $$\alpha=(x-yi)d(x+yi)+(z-wi)d(z+wi) \\ = xdx+xidy-yidx+ydy+zdz+zidw-widz+wdw.$$
Now, the problem is the terms with $i$. How can I get rid of these terms?

Comment: Why do you want to get rid of those terms?

Comment: @ArcticChar As the title suggests, I wanted to get the corresponding real one-form (if it exists) to $\alpha$.

Comment: You can get rid of the $i$s if and only if $\alpha$ is real to start with. Is. $\bar\alpha=\alpha$? Far from it. Try instead $\bar z_1dz_1+z_1d\bar z_1$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks. Your comment helped a lot.